# Sending an email in php is not working

Tags: php, email

Having an inquiry form in my website unable to send an email after entering an email and click on submit getting as "Mail could not be sent".It is redirecting to another and displaying the message.Need to display the message on the same page.Here is the code:

index.php

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="email" size="30" placeholder=" Enter your Email and Get Notified..."  name="email" id="email">
  <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn span btn-4 btn-4a icon-arrow-right"><span></span></button></a>
  <div id="response"></div>
</form>
```

contact.php:

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "mk_group", "12345") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("group", $connection);    
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$sql2 = mysql_query("insert into contact_us(email) values ('$email')");
if ($sql2) 
{
 $to = "xxx@gmail.com,yyy@gmail.com";
 $subject = 'the subject';
 $message = 'hello';         
 $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message);         
 echo "Message sent successfully...";
}else {
  echo "Message could not be sent...";
}
?>
```

Comment: Strongly recommend don't use `mysql_*` . use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: also vulnerable to sql injections

Comment: @MrProPop i need to send to different emails id

Comment: Just read the documentation .. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: what is the response of $sql2 ?

Comment: It is better to insert records in the database only when the email gets sent.

Answer (score 1):

Function `mail(string $to , string $subject , string $message)` requires 3 arguments and you set just one

Comment: Yeah as simple as that.